# Pressing back on last fragment shows blank Activity shortly before going to previous Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have two `Activities` and each one has 3-4 `Fragments` that each replace the other one.

When `Activity1`,`Fragment2` launches the second activity, `Activity2`,`Fragment1` is launched and `onBackPressed` closes the `Activity2` and goes back to `Activity1` as normally.

When I'm launching `Activity2` from `Activity1`,`Fragment3` though, I want to add `Fragment2` to the 2nd activity, which is done via cone in the `onCreate` method.

However, when the back button is pressed, the fragment disappears for a split second, leaving `Activity2` blank on the screen and after that `Activity2` is closed, resulting in a visual glitch.

Is there anything I can do to close `Activity2` the exact moment (at least at the same visual moment) as when `Fragment2` is being closed by the back button?

Thank you.

P.S.: Not adding the Fragment to the backStack seems to close the activity immediately, which is what happens in the first case (expected behavior), but when adding the Fragment to the backStack (as needed for correct operation in the second case) produces the glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after fighting with the backStack for many days, I decided to skip it, since it does not seem to be working properly, or I'm not understanding it.

The way I did it is on my Activity's `onBackPressed` i'm checking which fragment is showing and if it's the one that should be the last one (Multiple ones are the "last one") I just `finish()` the Activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("MyFragment");
    if (myFragment != null && myFragment .isVisible()) {
        //if myFragment is visible when the back button is pressed...
        finish();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to give a name to your fragment in the `FragmentManager` transaciton. In my case it is `"MyFragment"`.